# getting more info in HTMLLayout of log4j

Tags: html, layout, log4j

I have been using log4j 's *HTMLLayout* for getting logs in html format.However,it only allows 5 columns.I would like to get  the name of method where the logging request was issued.Is there any way to do this?(I know it is possible in *PatternLayout* using Conversion character M.But I don't think that option exists for HTMLLayout.

Any help appreciated

mark.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to change the htmllayout in log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583374/how-to-change-the-htmllayout-in-log4j)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way doing this for HTMLLayout. But you could write a CustomHTMLLayout that extends HTMLLayout so that you can get log in your specified HTML format.