# how to change the htmllayout in log4j

Tags: java, html, layout, log4j

i want to change the htmllayout (the 5 column - Time, Thread, Level, Category, Message) of log4j in Java.

my log4j.properties is:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Console, File

log4j.appender.Console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.File=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.File.File =${logfilename}

log4j.appender.Console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.File.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.Title=HTML Layout Example
log4j.appender.File.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
#[%d{MMM dd HH:mm:ss}] %-5p (%F:%L) - %m%n 

log4j.appender.File.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.Console.Threshold=DEBUG
```

i want to change the name of the "TIME" coloumn and to show there the current time.
Could anyone help me how to do it?

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution, which works.

```
package com.mypackage;  

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  
import java.util.Date;  
import java.util.regex.Matcher;  
import java.util.regex.Pattern;  

import org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent;  

/** 
 * This HTML Log Formatter is a simple replacement for the standard Log4J HTMLLayout formatter and 
 * replaces the default timestamp (milliseconds, relative to the start of the log) with a more readable 
 * timestamp (an example of the default format is 2008-11-21-18:35:21.472-0800). 
 * */  

public class   MyLayout  
       extends org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout  

{  
// RegEx pattern looks for <tr> <td> nnn...nnn </td> (all whitespace ignored)  

private static final String rxTimestamp = "\\s*<\\s*tr\\s*>\\s*<\\s*td\\s*>\\s*(\\d*)\\s*<\\s*/td\\s*>";  

//* The timestamp format. The format can be overriden by including the following   
  * property in the Log4J configuration file:  
  *  
  * log4j.appender.<category>.layout.TimestampFormat  
  *  
  * using the same format string as would be specified with SimpleDateFormat.  
  *  
  */  

private String timestampFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss.SZ"; // Default format. Example: 2008-11-21-18:35:21.472-0800  

private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(timestampFormat);  

public MyLayout()  
{  
super();  
}  

/** Override HTMLLayout's format() method */  

public String format(LoggingEvent event)  
{  
String record = super.format(event); // Get the log record in the default HTMLLayout format.  

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rxTimestamp);  // RegEx to find the default timestamp  
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(record);  

if (!matcher.find()) // If default timestamp cannot be found,  
{  
return record; // Just return the unmodified log record.  
}  

StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(record);   

buffer.replace(matcher.start(1), // Replace the default timestamp with one formatted as desired.  
       matcher.end(1),  
       sdf.format(new Date(event.timeStamp)));  

return buffer.toString(); // Return the log record with the desired timestamp format.  
}  

/** Setter for timestamp format. Called if log4j.appender.<category>.layout.TimestampFormat property is specfied */  

public void setTimestampFormat(String format)   
{  
    this.timestampFormat = format;  
this.sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(format); // Use the format specified by the TimestampFormat property  
}  

/** Getter for timestamp format being used. */  

public String getTimestampFormat()  
{  
return this.timestampFormat;  
}  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom layout that extends `org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout` class and overwrite the `format` method.

You can look at how formatting is the [code of HTMLLayout](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayout.java) and build your own version that suits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The piece that seemed to be missing from this solution is how to configure your newly extended `HTMLLayout` class so that it gets picked up and used when the exceptions are emailed.

Ours is working and we just needed this one liner added to our `log4j.properties` file.

```
log4j.appender.email.layout=com.<yourPackage>.utils.CustomizedHTMLLayout
```

Answer (score 0):

Configure your layout in below configuration

```
Log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

log4j.appender.FileAppender =org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FileAppender.File= C:\test.html
log4j.appender.FileAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.HTMLLayout

log4j.logger.<your packge>=FileAppender
```

Comment: i did it like you said "log4j.logger.com.financial.scotiatester=File.layout"
but nothing changed?

Comment: @Emrah Karakoc
Update the answer, just check it again

Comment: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.financial.scotiatester.ScotiaJunoLevel1Tester).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

i deleted my code in the properties file and wrote down yours. but i get the error now?

Comment: `No Appenders` : your log4j.properties in not `ClassPath`

Comment: but it is? i am using MAC. the log4j.properties is in my package. I get the error if i change the properties as you said.