# Can I collect logs (messages) from log4j into one java object

Tags: java, logging, log4j, report, generator

Instead of printing it to the console or writing in some file I want to collect all logs (i.e. messages) into some collection of String in Java object like this:

```
class LogCollector {
    List<String> messages;
}
```

That would make it easier for me to generate custom HTML report (just passing "LogCollector" object into some of methods). It would be preferable if I can implement this with Log4J.

**MORE DETAILED ISSUE:**
I want to make some class "LoggingPart":

```
class LoggingPart {
    String name;
    List<String> messages;
    List<LoggingPart> parts = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void start(String name) {
        parts.add(new LoggingPart(name));

        /* Logic that after every call LoggingPart.start("someName")  */
        /* in some other class will start collecting messages from    */
        /* logger into LoggingPart instance of name "someName"        */

        /* Report will be generated only of messages from particular  */
        /* instance with specified name                               */
    }
}
```

Comment: Look here : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_htmllayout.htm
isn't what you want to do ?

Comment: Ok, not exactly but you redirected me to interesting possible solution - overriding HtmlLayout's method format like it's answered on this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583374/how-to-change-the-htmllayout-in-log4j).
The thing is that I would in that case take this generated HTML by log4j, pull required info (log messages) from it (via regex?) and format it in a way I want to. Is there any way to skip that "pulling" step and get directly those messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been recommended many things, among all creating custom TestNG listener but the solution is really simple: make an additional log4j Appender:

1. Add Appender in log4j config file (log4j.properties)
2. Make a reference to your custom Appender class which will contain method for handling logs